# Console output delay with Python but not Java using PsExec

Tags: java, python, psexec

I have two files on a remote machine that I am running with PsExec, one is a Java program and the other Python.

For the Python file any outputs to screen (`print()` or `sys.stdout.write()`) are not sent back to my local machine until the script has terminated; for the Java program I see the output (`System.out.println()`) on my local machine as soon as it is created on the remote machine.

If anyone can explain to me why there is this difference and how to see the Python outputs as they are created I would be very grateful!

(Python 3.1, Remote Machine: Windows Server 2012, Local: Windows 7 32-bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the remote python script flushes the stdout?
It should get flushed every time you print a new line, or when you explicitly call sys.stdout.flush().

Comment: This was exactly my problem - thank you! For whatever reason the `print` output was buffering until the process ended. I called `python -u myfile.py` and the problem was solved.